# Implements of pooling or keep session alive in the openapi client generator for python

Tags: python, openapi, openapi-generator

I have an issue with my python client API that was generated by openapi-python-client version 0.11.5.
I want to implement a client that will use the same session all the time without the need to handle the SSL many times or implement get connection from the pool.

I have seen that the client generate code :

```
def sync_detailed(
    *,
    client: Client,
    all_fields: Union[Unset, None, bool] = False,
    service: str,
) -> Response[Res]:

    kwargs = _get_kwargs(
        client=client,
        all_fields=all_fields,
        service=service,
    )

    response = httpx.request(
        verify=client.verify_ssl,
        **kwargs,
    )

    return _build_response(response=response)
```

and I want to change that to :

```
async def asyncio_detailed(
    *,
    client: Client,
    all_fields: Union[Unset, None, bool] = False,
    service: str,
) -> Response[Res]:

    kwargs = _get_kwargs(
        client=client,
        all_fields=all_fields,
        service=service,
    )


    client.httpx_client.get
        verify=client.verify_ssl,
        **kwargs,
    )

    return _build_response(response=response)
```

I have take a look to :
[direct client](https://github.com/openapi-generators/openapi-python-client/issues/202)

and
[support custom template path](https://github.com/openapi-generators/openapi-python-client/pull/231)

I am just new in openapi and want to be sure that those links could be the solution, it will be great if the expert here can lead me to the best practice and some examples.

Thanks,

I have tried to understand the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue and have found short-term success by adding an attribute to the Client called httpx_client initialized with httpx.Client()

```
class Client:
    base_url: str
    cookies: Dict[str, str] = attr.ib(factory=dict, kw_only=True)
    headers: Dict[str, str] = attr.ib(factory=dict, kw_only=True)
    timeout: float = attr.ib(5.0, kw_only=True)
    verify_ssl: Union[str, bool, ssl.SSLContext] = attr.ib(True, kw_only=True)
    raise_on_unexpected_status: bool = attr.ib(False, kw_only=True)
    follow_redirects: bool = attr.ib(False, kw_only=True)
    httpx_client = httpx.Client()
```

Then swapping out the httpx.request with the httpx_client.

```
def sync_detailed(*, client: Client) -> Response[MessageResponse]:

    kwargs = _get_kwargs(
        client=client,
    )

    response = client.httpx_client.request(
        **kwargs,
    )

    return _build_response(client=client, response=response)
```

I have not re-added the verify_ssl  parameter. My results are approaching 2 orders of magnitude faster performanace due to not opening and closing the connection.